# How to test if a function is called by another function in vitest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vitest

I'm trying to test the **signup** function, which is a part of my code. This function creates a new user using the **User.create** method from Mongoose, and I want to ensure that this method is called during the execution of the **signup** function.

Here's my test code:

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import { signup } from '../controllers/authController';
import User from '../models/userModel';

vi.mock('../models/userModel');

describe('signup()', () => {
  const request = {
    firstName: 'first',
    lastName: 'last',
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    password: 'test-password',
    passwordConfirm: 'test-password',
    city: 'test-city',
    phoneNumber: +251946612595,
  };

  const response = {
    status: vi.fn().mockReturnThis,
    json: vi.fn().mockReturnThis,
    cookie: vi.fn(),
  };

  const mockNext = vi.fn();
  
  it('should call the create method from Mongoose', () => {
    // Mocking the User.create method to return the request object
    User.create.mockImplementationOnce(() => request);

    // Calling the signup function
    signup(request, response, mockNext);

    // Expecting that User.create is called at least once
    expect(User.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

However, my test is failing with the following error:

`AssertionError: expected "create" to be called at least once`

I tried mocking **User.create** without defining an implementation, expecting vitest to track its calls, but the test failure suggested that it was not called as anticipated within the **signup** function.

Comment: I know you didn't ask for this, but instead of making assertions that functions were called by other functions, I highly advocate not for this type of testing, but to actually test it deeper, test that the user ends up in the actual database. To do this, it's useful to have an in memory database: https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server

Comment: Also, I can see clearly now that you’re testing an api handler, the mocks are contrived, don’t do this.  The best approaches are to either start an api server in your test environment and use something like supertest to test the api completely through to the database, or to extract the logic that creates the user out of the handler and just test that extracted logic

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer to your question is to use a `spy`

https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-spyon

```
import User from '../models/userModel';

  // vi.mock('../models/userModel'); <- you don't need this line

  it('should call the create method from Mongoose', () => {
    // Mocking the User.create method to return the request object
    const spy = vi.spyOn(User,'create');

    // Calling the signup function
    signup(request, response, mockNext).mockImplementationOnce(() => request);

    // Expecting that User.create is called at least once
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I highly recommend you stop mocking response/next objects and either extract the user creation logic from the API handler and just test that extracted logic, or to start the API server in your test environment and just make a fetch (or equivalent) call. The more real your test is, the more you’ll benefit from it. The more contrived it is, the more useless it actually is because the likelihood of it failing incorrectly when implementation details change is higher (making people less cognizant if failed tests if “they always break for no good reason”) and the higher the maintenance cost